# Converting MySQL Stored Procedures to PostgreSQL function. What do I do with these replace() calls?

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I am just about finished converting 84 stored procedures from MySQL to PostgreSQL functions. The only thing that has not been figured out is what to do with the replace() calls. The function doesn't exist in PostgreSQL. I am sure someone has had to do this before. Any suggestions?

```
set @sql="CREATE TABLE `tbodefcall...(An UnGodly Amount of code that creates tables ...honeid_cd_idx (PhoneID,CallDate);";
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefcallback', concat('tbo_callback',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefcontact', concat('tbo_contact',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefscriptkvota', concat('tbo_scriptkvota',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefscript', concat('tbo_script',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodeftermcode', concat('tbo_termcode',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefprojectlogon', concat('tbo_projectlogon',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefcomment', concat('tbo_comment',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefvoicerecorder', concat('tbo_voicerecorder',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefquestiongroup', concat('tbo_questiongroup',_ProjectID) );
    set @sql =  Replace(@sql, 'tbodefquestion', concat('tbo_question',_ProjectID) );
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions. You guys have rocked in helping me through this project!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postgresql does have the `replace` function, at least in 8.4; which version are you using?

```
steve@steve@[local] =# select replace('create table tblfoo', 'tblfoo', 'tblfoo_44');
        replace         
------------------------
 create table tblfoo_44
(1 row)
```

Comment: No...PostgreSQL doesn't have replace()..I know that...I am using 8.4...I am trying to figure out what to do instead of replace.

Comment: And thanks araqnid... you've chimed in on every post I've made thus far and have been extremely helpful.

Comment: PostgreSQL has had a `replace` function since version 7.3.  If it doesn't work for you, please supply details.

Comment: I figured out why i didn't think replace() existed. MySQL has the REPLACE() that updates or deletes and inserts rows in a table. Everywhere I looked was bringing up this function. Which does not exist in Postgres. Thanks Everybody!

Answer (score 2):

You're actually looking for an "upsert" command. In PostgreSQL you perform it the following way:

```
UPDATE ...;
IF NOT FOUND THEN -- UPDATE didn't touch anything
  INSERT ...;
END IF;
```

Comment: that is what i originally thought as well, however i actually was looking for the string replacement function replace() that already exists in PostgreSQL